# Select Two Words before character in string in mysql

Tags: mysql, locate

I can find a given character using locate:

```
Select Locate(':','bla bla bla Favorite Color: Red yada yada')
```

But would like to select (at least) the word before it so in the above query I'd like to return 'Color'.

Ideally I'd love to return up to X Words where they are all init cap so in this case 'Favorite Color'. I'm assuming I'd need to add Binary and Regex for that but I can do so if I understand the basic structure of how to extract the word or words before the located character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to select the word just before `:` and the words separated by a space then you can use `substring_index` as

```
select 
 substring_index(
   substring_index('bla bla bla Favorite Color: Red yada yada',':',1)
   ,' ',-1
 ) as w ;
```

And if you want `Favorite Color` then change the index from `-1` to `-2`